# Urban Airship Development to production

Tags: android, push

I have created an app on urban airship in development mode and now using that application's keys in my project and now i sent that application on the google market. now how i can change the application status from development to production on my urban airship account?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't use development keys in a production environment.

You can find here an explanation of what you need to do for production app:
https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/questions/1291950-how-to-convert-development-app-into-production-app

I think the UA development app uses only test servers. If you want to publish your app to production, you need to create another UA app and put the new key and app secret in your code!